# Do I have to use train or test python model to import in my website?

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, classification

I have 2 python model to classify x-ray images. One python file to train the model and the other is to test the model. Now I want to make a website by using Flask and connect it with my machine learning model, so do I have to import my test or train model in the flask? Below is the example two of my code incase you would like to see.

Training Code:

```
# Importing modules:
from skimage.feature import hog, local_binary_pattern
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
from skimage.io import imread
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from skimage import color
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import glob
from sklearn import metrics
from PIL import Image 
from numpy import *

# define parameters of HOG feature extraction
orientations = 9
pixels_per_cell = (8, 8)
cells_per_block = (2, 2)
threshold = .3

dataset_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Train" # The path of dataset

# Read the image files:
category_im_listing = os.listdir(dataset_path) # Read all the files in the path
num_category_im = size(category_im_listing) # States the total no. of category
print("There are " + str(num_category_im) + " categories") # Prints the number value of the no.of categories dataset
data= []
labels = []
count = 0

# compute HOG features and label them:
for category in category_im_listing: # Enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
    im_listing = os.listdir(dataset_path + "/" + category)
    num_im = size(im_listing)
    print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images in category " + str(count + 1))
    for file in im_listing:
        img = Image.open(dataset_path + "/" + category + "/" + file) # open the file
        img = img.resize((150,150))
        gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image into single channel 
        # calculate HOG for positive features
        fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True) # fd= feature descriptor
        data.append(fd)
        labels.append(count)
    count = count + 1

# encode the labels, converting them from strings to integers
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)

#%% Train the linear SVM
print(" Training Linear SVM classifier with HOG...")
model = svm.LinearSVC(multi_class='ovr')
model.fit(trainData, trainLabels)

#%% Evaluate the classifier
print(" Evaluating classifier on test data ...")
predictions = model.predict(testData)
print(classification_report(testLabels, predictions))
print("Validation Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(testLabels, predictions))

# Save the model:
joblib.dump(model, 'HOG_SVM.npy')
```

Testing Code:

```
from skimage.feature import hog, local_binary_pattern
from skimage.transform import pyramid_gaussian
import joblib
from skimage import color
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob
from numpy import *

# Define HOG Parameters
# change them if necessary to orientations = 8, pixels per cell = (16,16), cells per block to (1,1) for weaker HOG
orientations = 9
pixels_per_cell = (8, 8)
cells_per_block = (2, 2)
threshold = .3
classes = open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\classes.txt').read().strip().split("\n")

model = joblib.load('HOG_SVM.npy')
test_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test"
im_listing = os.listdir(test_path)
num_im = size(im_listing)
print("There are " + str(num_im) + " images to be tested")

for file in im_listing:
    img = cv2.imread(test_path + "/" + file)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (150,150))
    fds = hog(img, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2')  # extract HOG features from the window captured

fds = fds.reshape(1, -1) 
pred = model.predict(fds)
img = cv2.resize(img, (550,350))
file = str(file).split(".")

cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Result\Test' + file[0] + '_' + classes[int(pred)] + '_HOG_SVM.jpg',img)

cv2.imshow(classes[int(pred)] + '_HOG_SVM.jpg' , img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Save the model:
joblib.dump(model, 'HOG_SVM_TEST.npy')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one model, the model on which you trained your data. You are saving your model in the training code through this: `joblib.dump(model, 'HOG_SVM.npy')`. Use this model with your Flask backend. When you test your model you do not make any changes to the model itself, you just test it against unseen data. Through testing you can get reliable metrics like accuracy, from which you can decide if your model is good enough for your application or not. Hence, `joblib.dump(model, 'HOG_SVM_TEST.npy')` is totally redundant as you already have this model.